# How can I set up a Google Apps email address to forward?

Tags: google-apps-email

I have tried following the instructions [from Google Support](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?answer=175745), but when I get to step 4:

> In the Email routing section, click Add another destination.

I can't proceed because there is no Email routing section.

Comment: If you use the free version of Google Apps, you can't use the instructions you listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you the account admin? You can't set up user-level forwarding if you have a free Google Apps account, but the users can configure it themselves: [Google Support](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=10957)

Answer (score 1):

User-level routing is available in Google Apps for Business and Education.

Comment: So there is no way I can forward emails with their free (< 10 email addresses) account?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Apps for Education, there is also have the option of creating an email alias without the need of another account. 
For example, my account is user@domain.org. With email aliases, I can have e-mail sent to alias1@domain.org, alias2@domain.org, alias3@domain.org, etc. all come to user@domain.org. See these [Google Apps Support Docs](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182527).

As far as forwarding from one actual account to another, you are limited to receiving mail from only one other account. [See this](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2707558).

It's a quick and easy setup, but it does have to be done by an Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Apps > Gmail > Default Routing
Set default routing:
Enter New email address: jondoe@example.com
Under #2 click "Also deliver to: Add more recipients"
Under #3 leave "Perform this action only on non-recognized addresses" clicked

Under Apps User Account:
Aliases > Set Alias: jondoe@example.com

Now setup "send email as" for jondoe@example.com in the @gmail.com
smtp.gmail.com
Port 465 SSL
Username: jondoe@example.com
Password: Password of jondoe@example.com
Done

Now make jondoe@example.com default if you want.

Now Set a Filter in the Google Apps User Gmail Acct to skip the inbox, delete it and forward to the alias @gmail.com account

Test and Success!

Answer (score 0):

For the free Google Apps account (which they're not giving away anymore) you have to burn a user account for this, as these accounts do not come with mail routing. Create a user account, then setup mail forwarding.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can configure forwarding in the mail-settings of the account (as well as with every "normal" Gmail-account).